# Send 50 AJAX requests, and delay 10 seconds after every 5 requests, then continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to send 50 AJAX requests, and delay 10 seconds after every 5 requests then continue and do not send the next request until the previous one is sent successfully.
I also want to create an alert after the required number of requests is completed.

this my code

```
var requestCount = 50; // Replace X with the number of requests you want to make
var requestDelay = 5; // Delay in seconds between every 10th request
var requestCounter = 0;

function makeRequest() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "request.php?action=manualGroupMembers",
    success: function(response) {
      // Handle response here
    },
    error: function(error) {
      // Handle error here
    }
  });

  requestCounter++;

  // Wait for 10 seconds after every 10th request
  if (requestCounter % 10 === 0) {
    setTimeout(makeRequest, requestDelay * 1000);
  } else {
    makeRequest();
  }
}

makeRequest();
```

This code currently sends 5 requests with a 10-second delay, but I only want it to send 50 requests. Additionally, it sends all the requests simultaneously which leads to an issue. I want the code to wait until the previous request is successfully sent before sending the next one..

Comment: But what is your _question_? What is the relevance of the code you’ve shown? See how to create a [mre]; in particular, [edit] your post and add a _specific problem description_. Is the URL always the same? Have you tried using [`Promise`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here, or the jQuery equivalent, [Deferred Objects](//api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object)? They might make this a bit easier.

Comment: @SebastianSimon sorry, i edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend switching to an async/await syntax, which will make the code much easier to follow, then it's only a matter of sleeping for X number of seconds after Y requests :)

```
const requestCount = 50; // Replace X with the number of requests you want to make
const delayAfterNumberOfRequest = 10; // Delay after this number of requests
const requestDelay = 10; // Delay in seconds between every Xth request
const responses = [];

const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function makeRequests() {
  for (let i = 0; i < requestCount; i++) {
    let response = await $.ajax('request.php?action=manualGroupMembers')
      .catch(e => /* handle error */ true);
    responses.push(response);
    if (i > 0 && i % delayAfterNumberOfRequest === 0) {
      await sleep(requestDelay * 1000);
    }
  }
}

async function test() {
  await makeRequests();
  console.log(responses);
}

test();
```